# Prediction probability of each label in BERT classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, nlp

I am trying to implement a method to evaluate prediction probability as is done with the help of scikit learn's

```
confidence = model._predict_proba_lr(x_count).max() * 100
```

Is there a way to evaluate the same using **BERT Models**?

Currently using Bert Base Uncased.
Using Ktrain Library(using Keras internally)
Reference Code : https://github.com/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/examples/text/20newsgroups-BERT.ipynb

Answer (score 2):

In *ktrain*, you can pass `return_proba=True` to the `predictor.predict` method to output probabilities.  See the [text classification tutorial](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial-04-text-classification.ipynb) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the specific code you are using. But for classification (I guess this is what you're looking for), BERT uses a linear + soft-max layer over the last layer of the pre-trained BERT. So computing probabilities should be straightforward. I found [an example with ktrain](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/amaiya/ktrain/blob/master/tutorial-04-text-classification.ipynb) apparently where you can specify that you want probabilities (line 23).